# Add string in between variables for GNU Make

Tags: windows, makefile, gnu

I have this

```
SRC = file1.c file2.c file3.c
```

How do I make it into

```
file1.c + file2.c + file3.c
```

The closest I can get is (note the '+' sign at the end)

```
file1.c + file2.c + file3.c +
```

using

```
SRC2 := $(SRC:.c=.c +)
```

Comment: For what do you need the + between the filenames? Do you want `SRC += file1.c file2.c file3.c`?

Comment: Need to merge the content of the file by using simple Windows copy command. `copy /b file1.c + file2.c + file3.c output.bin`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
SRC=abc def ghi
SRC2=$(word 1,$(SRC))$(foreach f,$(wordlist 2,99999,$(SRC)), + $(f))
all:
        @echo $(SRC2)
```

That is, peel off the first word, then unconditionally add each additional word with the "+" prefix.

Here's another, only works if you're sure you have exactly one space between each word in `SRC`.

```
EMPTY=
SPACE=$(EMPTY) $(EMPTY)
SRC=abc def ghi
SRC2=$(subst $(SPACE), $(SPACE)+$(SPACE),$(SRC))
all:
        @echo $(SRC2)
```

This time the idea is to replace a single space character with the sequence space-plus-space.  Make sure you don't have a space between the comma and `$(SRC)`!

Comment: Thanks both solutions works. I do found out another way. `SRC2 = $(subst .c,.c +,$(subst $(lastword $(SRC)),,$(SRC)))$(lastword $(SRC))`